# AWS Container to Ping Second Interface

Tags: docker, networking, nat, amazon-ecs

I'm facing a weird issue. One EC2 instance with two interfaces:

```
eth0: 10.0.0.57
eth2: 10.0.1.8
```

An ECS container is started in bridge network mode. Ping to 10.0.0.57 goes through. Ping to 10.0.1.8 does not get reply. The same container can ping interfaces from the same subnet 10.0.1.* if they are attached to other instances, but not the local instance. Not sure how to approach this.

It doesn't seem related but other instances can ping the 10.0.1.8.

Here are my route tables:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         ip-10-0-0-1.ec2 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         ip-10-0-1-1.ec2 0.0.0.0         UG    10002  0        0 eth2
10.0.0.0        *               255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth0
10.0.1.0        *               255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 eth2
instance-data.e *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
```

TCP dump on the host shows that request is received but there is no reply

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on docker0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
06:10:02.788057 IP ip-172-17-0-3.ec2.internal > ip-10-0-1-8.ec2.internal: ICMP echo request, id 2038, seq 0, length 64
```

Added route tables entries:

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-52 ec2-user]# ip route show table all
default via 10.0.1.1 dev eth1  table 10001
10.0.1.0/26 dev eth1  table 10001  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.1.8
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0
default via 10.0.1.1 dev eth1  metric 10001
10.0.0.0/26 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.52
10.0.1.0/26 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.1.8
169.254.169.254 dev eth0
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
broadcast 10.0.0.0 dev eth0  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.52
local 10.0.0.52 dev eth0  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 10.0.0.52
broadcast 10.0.0.63 dev eth0  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.52
broadcast 10.0.1.0 dev eth1  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.1.8
local 10.0.1.8 dev eth1  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 10.0.1.8
broadcast 10.0.1.63 dev eth1  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.1.8
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 127.0.0.1
broadcast 172.17.0.0 dev docker0  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
local 172.17.0.1 dev docker0  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 172.17.0.1
broadcast 172.17.255.255 dev docker0  table local  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
unreachable ::/96 dev lo  metric 1024  error -113 pref medium
unreachable ::ffff:0.0.0.0/96 dev lo  metric 1024  error -113 pref medium
unreachable 2002:a00::/24 dev lo  metric 1024  error -113 pref medium
unreachable 2002:7f00::/24 dev lo  metric 1024  error -113 pref medium
unreachable 2002:a9fe::/32 dev lo  metric 1024  error -113 pref medium
unreachable 2002:ac10::/28 dev lo  metric 1024  error -113 pref medium
unreachable 2002:c0a8::/32 dev lo  metric 1024  error -113 pref medium
unreachable 2002:e000::/19 dev lo  metric 1024  error -113 pref medium
unreachable 3ffe:ffff::/32 dev lo  metric 1024  error -113 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth1  proto kernel  metric 256  pref medium
fe80::/64 dev docker0  proto kernel  metric 256 linkdown  pref medium
unreachable default dev lo  proto kernel  metric 4294967295  error -101 pref medium
local ::1 dev lo  table local  proto none  metric 0  pref medium
local fe80::42:efff:fe9c:756d dev lo  table local  proto none  metric 0  pref medium
local fe80::103b:91ff:fe01:1b38 dev lo  table local  proto none  metric 0  pref medium
local fe80::1065:f1ff:fea5:ba1e dev lo  table local  proto none  metric 0  pref medium
ff00::/8 dev eth0  table local  metric 256  pref medium
ff00::/8 dev eth1  table local  metric 256  pref medium
ff00::/8 dev docker0  table local  metric 256 linkdown  pref medium
unreachable default dev lo  proto kernel  metric 4294967295  error -101 pref medium
```

I did some debugging and the ping to the local second interface increases Nat-prerouting packet count (tested with "iptables -vL -t nat" command), filter-forward count ( "iptables -vL -t filter" ) and mangle-prerouting ("iptables -vL -t mangle")

Where as ping to the local first interface increases filter-input and, filter-output, mangle-prerouting, mangle-input, mangle-output packet counts.

Need to find a way for the container to be able to ping all local interfaces. Cannot modify the docker bridge network, also cannot run the container in host mode. Would appreciate help on this.

Thanks in advance,
Ruben

Answer (score 1):

Check ip rules on EC2

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-57 ec2-user]# ip rule
0:      from all lookup local
32765:  from 10.0.0.192 lookup 10001
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

delete 32765 rule

```
ip rule del prio  32765
```

after that rules should be like

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-57 ec2-user]# ip rule
0:      from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

and then ping and other traffic will be passed just fine

Comment: This works as a temporary solution. After about 15 minutes the rule gets recreated.

Comment: Also, removing the rule prevents the interface to be accessible from the network.